# XSLT, Extract sub-string from xml using regex

Tags: regex, xslt

I am trying to apply XSLT on SVN log, I need to extract bug numbers from the commit messages. I am applying this regex on msg but get nothing back. What am I missing in XSLT?
Thank you in advance
Below is XML that I get from SVN:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<log>
 <logentry revision="265">
 <author>dre</author>
    <date>2015-04-13T02:35:25.246150Z</date>
    <msg>modified code</msg>
</logentry>
<logentry revision="73283">
 <author>john</author>
 <date>2015-04-13T14:10:20.987159Z</date>
 <msg>fixed bug DESK-1868</msg>
</logentry>
<logentry revision="73290">
 <author>ron</author>
 <date>2015-04-13T14:24:57.475711Z</date>
 <msg>WEBAPP-1868 Fix for pallete list and settings dialog Selected Tab Index</msg>
</logentry>
</log>
```

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>
  <h2>SVN Issues</h2>
    <table border="1">
      <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
        <th style="text-align:left">ver</th>
        <th style="text-align:left">author</th>
        <th style="text-align:left">date</th>
        <th style="text-align:left">ticket</th>
      </tr>
      <xsl:for-each select="log/logentry">
      <tr>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="@revision"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="author"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="date"/></td>
        <td>
            
                <xsl:variable name="messageValue" select="msg"/>
                <xsl:analyze-string select="$messageValue" 
                  regex="(DESK|TRS|PEK|WEBAPP)-\d{4}$">
                      <xsl:matching-substring>
                         <bug><xsl:value-of select="regex-group(1)"/></bug>
                      </xsl:matching-substring>
                </xsl:analyze-string>
        </td>
      </tr>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I changed the version, but still not getting anything in back for that field

Comment: You need to double up your `{}` in your regex...`regex="(DESK|TRS|PEK|WEBAPP)-\d{{4}}$"`. http://xsltransform.net/94rmq5D (Not sure why you're using `$` to match the end of the string. It will only return something on the second logentry like that.) Also, be sure that you're using an XSLT 2.0 processor.

Comment: double {} helped, and I am usig XSLT 2.0 now. I see DESK as a result.

Comment: instead of using `regex-group()`, use `.` instead. See the link in my previous comment. It returns what you want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#analyze-string

   > **Note:** Because the regex attribute is an attribute value template, curly brackets within the regular expression must be doubled. For
   >   example, to match a sequence of one to five characters, write
   >   `regex=".{{1,5}}"`. For regular expressions containing many curly
   >   brackets it may be more convenient to use a notation such as
   >   `regex="{'[0-9]{1,5}[a-z]{3}[0-9]{1,2}'}"`, or to use a variable.
2. You do not want to anchor your expression to the end of the line using `$` at the end of your expression. Otherwise the regex will only match when the message ends with an issue ID.

Use this regex expression to capture the entire bug number:

```
regex="((DESK|TRS|PEK|WEBAPP)-\d{{4}})"
```

Comment: Almost work... When I test the regex against a string I get WEBAPP-1868, but when I use it in XSL - I only get WEBAPP

Comment: Do you want the number, or the entire bug ID? Simply adjust the regex to put the parenthesis for the capture group to include what you want.  It is helpful to specify the desired outcome in your question.

Comment: I wanted WEBAPP-1868. After adding parenthesis I get exactly what I wanted. Thank you.